# Objects in viewForItemAtIndex

Tags: iphone, xml

Im using a UITableview to display data from a NSDictionary from TouchXML. TouchXML is a system to integrate XML feeds within my iPhone application.

For the Tableview this all works, i put the NSdictionary  like this in my UITableview:

```
[[[newsEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"still"] retain];
```

Now i am using the iCarousel software, its an opensource CoverFlow like system. Before i have used the AFOpenFlowView but this is just a pain becouse it won't accept UIViews. Only images.

I need to load thumbnails in the iCarousel from the XML. So i need to get a string from the dictionary and change it to a UIImage.

I made this work. The problem i'm having is that i need to load multiple images in the iCarousel just like you would load multiple images/thumbnails in your TableView row.
Now i need to do the same with the iCarousel, but how?

This is how fare i currently am. Problem is a TableView has a indexPath.row and this viewForItemAtIndex doesn't.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    //create a numbered view
    NSString *imageUrl = [[[newsEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"still"] retain];
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    UIView *view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds] autorelease];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [[items objectAtIndex:index] intValue]];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
    [view addSubview:label];
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't replacing `indexPath.row` with `index` work?

```
NSString *imageUrl = [[[newsEntries objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"still"] retain];
```

Comment: Then i get a Index beyond bounds 1...19

Comment: If the index is one off, then you can always subtract one like `objectAtIndex:(index - 1)`.

Comment: What do you return for `numberOfItemsInCarousel:`?

Comment: And how are `newsEntries` and `items` related? Ideally you would use the same array right?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
  return [items count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is response when i log the string with the object for key

```
2011-06-01 14:57:51.273 [711:207] my url = (null)
2011-06-01 14:57:51.277 [711:207] my url = (null)
```

etc. etc. etc.